How to recover Ubuntu 22.04 GPU working using command line
My knowledge of Linux is limited. Ubuntu 22.04 was working fine. It recommended Ubuntu 24.04. When I started upgrade command, the computer hung up. I had no choice but to shut down the computer and power up. After many days on Stack Exhange, I can now login to Ubuntu 22.04 in command line. But I can't get to the GPU mode. What file(s) I am missing, and how do I get back to normal power up so that I can resume my Python jobs?
Also I do not know whether I have Nvidia GPU. How can I find out?

This question is similar to: Switching between virtual console (tty) and GUI. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
